# Change value in if statement in Shell script

Tags: bash, shell, if-statement

I would like to change the value of the global variable `status` in my script below, but I don't know what's wrong with this.

```
status="alive";
for i in (*code here*)
do 
  ping -c3 (*host modified by the code*) > /dev/null
  if [ $? -eq 0 ]
  then
    status="alive";
  else
    status="dead";
  fi

  if [ "$status" == "alive" ]
  then    
  (*code here*)
  fi
```

this status variable used to check whether host is down or not, if host is not down, then do the ping and otherwise.

So is the last if statement working correctly ??? Please show me where i have mistake. Thanks in advanced!!

PROBLEM SOLVED!!!!

Comment: What is `i` and how is it used? What host is passed to `ping`?

Comment: i is the host inside a text file containing a list of host.

Comment: Of course it pings all the hosts.  You don't test if the host is alive or dead before doing the ping.  The question is, it your last if statement `status == alive` working correctly?

Comment: yes. Thank you! So can you show me the error here ??

Answer (score 0):

```
status="alive";
for i in (*code here*)
do 
  ping -c3 (*host modified by the code*) > /dev/null
  if [ $? -eq 0 ]
  then
    status="alive";
  else
    status="dead";
  fi

  if [ "$status" == "alive" ]
  then    
    (*code here*)
  fi
done    #<-- this was missing!!
```

Comment: The part of the code that you showed (including `done`) works without problem (tested). So, the error MUST be in the what you DID NOT show us. Run the script with the -x option so you can see where it goes wrong. If all else fails: copy and paste the COMPLETE code.